# Flex datagrid unicode characters

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, encoding

So i was asked to build a flex application to store clients for a local business. However it needs to store the clients using Greek characters. My problem is that when importing a name in the datagrid in Greek it work Î›ÎµÏ‰Î½Î¯Î´Î±Ï‚ When i try to put it in the database using phpmyadmin it seems to be ok but then it comes like ??????????? in the datagrid. My set is flex application connecting to mysql using php services. I have setted the encoding of the database to be utf8-general with no luck. Im not sure if this is a problem with flex or with the services. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research in greek flex and php forums i found out a solution. in order to access any utf8 language from flex the only thing that needs to be done is to add

```
mysqli_query($this->connection, "set names utf8");
```

before any sql statements in the methods of the service files (getAllSomething). This will allow to write and retrieve utf8 charsets in any language without a problem.

i hope this will be helpful to other flex developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=768105) forum discussion presents ideas for how to use special characters in Flash/Flex including Greek characters. See Kostas Zotos' post for a potential solution with these building blocks:

- Use utf-8 encoding.
- Use an xml file with a CDATA block to list greek characters.
- Use device fonts, not embedded fonts.